# Relink element from one branch to another

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I'm trying to create an element at a location on branch `b_new`. Unfortunately it already exists at branch `b_old`, but `b_old` is destined to die at some point in the future. Anyway, when I try to create the element, I get the following message:

> The correct way is to merge or link object from another branch.

So how should this linking be done? I don't want to merge it as `b_old` is plainly wrong, but I don't have the rights to delete it. Should I be concerned about the evil twin, or will the removal of branch `b_old` solve the problem automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cleartool ln](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_ln.htm?lang=en) might not be a good idea, considering that:

> You can attach attributes and hyperlinks, but not version labels, to a VOB symbolic link.
>   **You cannot check out a VOB symbolic link**.

You can try and add your element, by:

- checkout the parent folder
- use  `cleartool merge`: see "[to merge selective versions from a subbranch](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/to_merge_select_branch.htm?lang=en)"
- checkin the parent folder

The idea is to record in your current branch, and in the parent folder a version of that file from the old branch.
Once that version is referenced in your current branch, you will be able to checkout that file and modify it, adding new versions in your current branch starting from the merged version.